# More comments takes focus to the comment field

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, user-interface, mobile

When I click on "more comments" in a question (for example at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24247/tex-capacity-exceeded-sorry-input-stack-size-5000)), the comment field gets the focus. Which is annoying on the iPad because the keyboard gets visible and takes up half the screen. It would be great if no text input area / field has the focus as we then would be able to view the comments (as requested by clicking on the 'add / see more comments). I know that this is also the button for adding comments, but the behavior slightly annoys me when I only want to read the remaining comments.

Comment: I think the answer to this one will be: The site is optimized for normal screens, on which this problem isn't a problem; for mobile devices, there's the mobile version. The iPad and other tablets are something in between, unfortunately.

Comment: @doncherry The mobile version has the same problem.

Comment: We're [planning on making changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111697/show-n-more-comments-grabs-focus-kills-cursor-keys) to the "add / show X more comments."

Comment: @JarrodDixon Thank you very much for the pointer!

Comment: @PatrickGundlach we have [balpha](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/users/1106/balpha) to thank for the fixes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, doncherry is right:

> I think the answer to this one will be: The site is optimized for normal screens, on which this problem isn't a problem; for mobile devices, there's the mobile version. The iPad and other tablets are something in between, unfortunately.

A lot of the issues that the iPad interface has to deal with -- weird skipping, screen real estate issues, etc -- are usually covered by switching to the mobile view. Of course, having *actually used* an iPad to surf the site, I can say that I really dislike the chat interface in mobile. So, I sympathize but unfortunately, switching to mobile is the better option, even if a good amount of the functionality changes in the switch. It's up to you to make the call; screen real estate vs. function.

Comment: Well, the site is almost perfectly usable using an iPad. It's really so much fun to use it. I rather don't use the 'show more comments' feature than to switch the super ugly mobile version that has the same problem.

Comment: Ahh. I don't really like the mobile version either, but it *is* (theoretically) better suited for tablet and mobile devices. Either way, the answer I gave you is (effectively) the standard answer. My apologies. But -- I *am* glad to hear it's fun to surf the site on an iPad. I have a Kindle Fire, myself, and I haven't used it on SO/SE yet. :D

Comment: But the mobile version has the same problem... (using it right now)

Comment: Looks like you've gotten your answer. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! - I'll accept this answer even it it doesn't really the whole truth, just to make sure this issue is not open anymore.